# Call async method from sync action methods: Task.Run or ConfigureAwaits(false)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task, deadlock

I can prevent deadlock for **Result** call for async Task in sync action method of controller using both: **ConfigureAwaits(false)** on Task or using **Task.Run**. In both cases async method will be completed on thread from threadpool. Controller source:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Thread from threadpool will be used to finish async method.
    /// </summary>
    public string TaskRun()
    {
        return Task.Run(GetStatus).Result + " <br/> " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// After completion it will try to finish async method in original thread used to work for httprequest.
    /// </summary>
    public string Deadlock()
    {
        return GetStatus().Result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Thread from threadpool will be used to finish async method.
    /// </summary>
    public string AwaitsFalse()
    {
        return GetStatusAwaitsFalse().Result + " <br/> " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
    }

    public async Task<string> PureAsync()
    {
        return await GetStatus() + " <br/> " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetStatusAwaitsFalse()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com")
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
            return response.StatusCode + " - " + 
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
        }
    }

    public static async Task<string> GetStatus()
    {
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = await httpClient.GetAsync("http://www.google.com");
            return response.StatusCode + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " - " +
                Thread.CurrentThread.IsThreadPoolThread;
        }
    }
}
```

Output from **/test/taskrun** (two last int values are ManagedThreadId and IsThreadPoolThread):

```
OK - 12 - True 
6 - True
```

Output from **/test/awaitsfalse** is the same. Is there any difference?

Comment: Step back a second: why are you using a synchronous action to call async methods in the first place?

Comment: @CharlesMager because it's interesting. I understand how it works with "pure async" approach. Now I'm trying to find out bad cases to understand it more deep.

Comment: Additionally according to best practices for async-await you should "Use ConfigureAwait(false) when you can" ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx ). It prevents deadlock in case of calling Result on UI thread. So it's interesting for me: can I do the same in another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no universal solution for sync-over-async, only a variety of anti-patterns that each have different problems. For detailed information, see my [MSDN article on brownfield async](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx).

The problem with `ConfigureAwait(false)` is that it must be applied *everywhere* - for every `await` in the transitive closure of called methods. It's *really easy* to miss one and then you have a deadlock waiting to happen. For example, last time I checked, `HttpClient.GetAsync` is missing one for one of their mobile platform builds. And even if you (and all your dependencies) do this *perfectly*, it's just as hard to *maintain* over time.

The problem with `Task.Run` is that it runs the code on a thread pool thread. (Obviously). This is fine for code that *can* run on a thread pool thread, but that's just not the case for all code. It's also less efficient, and (if overused) can cause scalability problems on ASP.NET.

P.S. If you insist on blocking, use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Result`, because `Result` will wrap exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

Comment: "and (if overused) can cause scalability problems on ASP.NET." - To expand upon this with a worst-case scenario: If you end up exhausting your thread pool, further calls to `Task.Run` may block while waiting for a thread.  This results in what I call "deadlock yarn": It's not necessarily a true deadlock, but every additional request wraps another loop around your unresponsive code, preventing the deadlock yarn from having a chance to untangle.  I'll note that Visual Studio's dump analysis tool is pretty good at tracing sync-over-async responsiveness issues.