# Why make an awaitable synchronous doesn't work in a separate method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I want to make an async method running synchronously.

Yes, I know it's a bad practice but there are several reasons we need that and therefore let's assume for the sake of this question that we must do this and there is no other way to achieve the final result.

So I have my async method

```
public static async Task AsyncMethod();
```

If I call it in this way:

```
public static void SyncMethod()
{
  Task task = Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMethod(); });
  task.Wait();
}
```

everything works fine.

But if I want to generalize my approach and place this logic in a separate method, in an utilities library (such library is a separate one from my UWP project), the method never returns. Here's the code with the approach that doesn't work:

```
public static class Utilities
{
public static void Sync(this Task task)
{
    if (task == null)
        return;

    Task t = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            s_log.InfoFormat("Exception while running task {0} due to {1}", task.Id, e.Message);
        }
    });
    t.Wait();
}
}
```

And to call the method I simply do:

```
public static void SyncMethod()
{
  AsyncMethod().Sync();
}
```

Can anybody explain this dichotomy please?

EDIT:

Due to the early comments to the questions, let me clarify the final purpose of this question.

The problem is not how to solve the Sync vs. async anti-pattern. I have already a good solution for that, and I explain it in the first part of the question.

Moreover, there is another question ([Call async method from sync action methods: Task.Run or ConfigureAwaits(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329353/call-async-method-from-sync-action-methods-task-run-or-configureawaitsfalse)) that explains the pros and cons of the solution, etc.

The problem instead is understanding why those 2 lines of code

```
  Task task = Task.Run(async () => { await AsyncMethod(); });
  task.Wait();
```

work "in-line", but if I place them in a different method (in another library) they don't work anymore.

Please find an MVCE here: https://github.com/cghersi/UWPExamples/tree/master/SyncAntiPattern

Comment: it's probably swallowing an exception - it would be thrown at the Wait, not in that try/catch you have there, if i recall, and since your method is void, that's what's killing it

Comment: this is an old article, but you're using an old pattern (async as sync) so it might be of some value, especially the exceptions and void thing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: Why are you spawning up a new task to do something sync?

Comment: What kind of application is this? Console? ASP.NET? WinForms? WPF?

Comment: Couldn't you just `task.Wait()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call async method from sync action methods: Task.Run or ConfigureAwaits(false)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329353/call-async-method-from-sync-action-methods-task-run-or-configureawaitsfalse)

Comment: @Nikki9696 I added try-catch everywhere, plus an overall Exception handler in my UQP project, but no Exception is thrown here :( Plus, thanks for mentioning the article, but unfortunately it provides guidelines that are not entirely true (I tried unsuccessfully)

Comment: @KennethK. this is an UWP app

Comment: @Amy and johnny5: this is the only way I found effective to solve my problem. The real question is not how to solve the problem, which I did, but why the very same code works if placed in the same method and instead doesn't work if I move it to another method!

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Let's make an analogy. Suppose you are in the business of delivering packages. The workflow should be "while we are waiting for the truck to be available, find other work to do".  But the workflow you have written is "hire a worker who writes a todo list that says to find other work to do while you're waiting for the truck to be available, and then hire another worker to do what is on that list, and then hire yet another worker to watch the first two workers and do nothing until they finish." None of this makes the truck get back faster; it wastes workers.

Comment: @CristianoGhersi is it possible for you to post something that's a full example of the problem, such that we could copy it into a project and run it and see the behavior?

Comment: @Nikki9696 I edited the question with an MVCE to repro the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have already a good solution for that, and I explain it in the first part of the question.

You have [one hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). Like every hack, it won't work everywhere.

Minor improvement: use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` instead of `Wait()`; this would avoid the `AggregateException` wrapper in failure conditions.

> The problem instead is understanding why those 2 lines of code work "in-line", but if I place them in a different method (in another library) they don't work anymore.

The difference is in where `AsyncMethod` is called. In the code that works (avoids the deadlock), `AsyncMethod` is called from within the `Task.Run`, i.e., on a thread pool thread. Thus, it does not capture its context and avoids the [deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html). In the code that doesn't work, `AsyncMethod` is called from the UI thread and then the thread pool thread is just used to (asynchronously) wait for the task to complete; so `AsyncMethod` captures the UI context and you're back to having a deadlock.

Comment: You made my day, man! Yes, I modified the MVCE so now it works perfectly, the trick has been to pass a Func<Task> to my Sync() method, so that it executed exactly as you said! BTW, I know it is a hack, but life is far from ideal sometimes... ;)

Comment: Thank you for linking to that blog post! I knew things deadlocked but never truly understood WHY.